# Using small CNN for de-noising on a full image

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, cnn, convolution

I have trained a CNN, in Keras, to remove noise from an image, the input shape is (5,5) and I trained it by using patches from an image with noise with the expected output for the center pixel.

To enumerate, the input shape is (5,5) the output is one value.

Now, I want to use my CNN on a full, large, image. Is there any way to take my input image (1024x1024) and run it through the CNN without having to split this image into 5x5 patches?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, since you trained on patches of the image, you will need to feed in patches. This will make the denoising process of a large image very slow.